# get more than three months data in sql

Tags: mysql

I am writing a script that will give me all account numbers where deposit and withdrwals has not been done for more than three month of current date. I have written a script which gives me all accounts with deposit and withdrwals upto  current month but i want only the accounts of more than three month. here is the script i wrote:

```
SELECT Ca.accountnumber, 
       Ca.cuaccountid, 
       CP.description   AS product, 
       Max(ct.valuedate)AS ltd, 
       CA.balancedate 
FROM   cutransaction ct 
       JOIN cuproduct CP 
         ON ct.productid = Cp.productid 
       JOIN cuaccount CA 
         ON Ca.cuaccountid = ct.cuaccountid 
WHERE  CP.producttypeid = 1 
       AND CA.active = 1 
       AND CP.active = 1 
       AND ct.transactiontypeid IN ( 1, 2 ) 
       AND ct. transactionsourceid = 1 
       AND CP.productid IN( 117, 118, 119, 120, 
                            121, 122, 123, 124, 125 ) 
GROUP  BY Ca.accountnumber, 
          Ca.cuaccountid, 
          CP.description, 
          CA.balancedate 
ORDER  BY CA.accountnumber
```

please use max(ct,valuedate) as the column for the date

Comment: So what is the problem? if you already have the latest transaction date, why you dont check if that is 3 months old?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT YQ.* 
FROM (YourQuery) YQ
WHERE YQ.ltd < (CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
```